# Don't get any data though the binary file is already filled with data

Tags: java, io

```
System.out.println("======================================");
System.out.println("List of Ships and their revenue");
System.out.println("======================================");

try
   {
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (fileName));

    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem");
    }

try
    {
    while (true)
    {
        Ship copyObject = (Ship)inputStream.readObject();
        System.out.println(copyObject.getShipName() + "       " + copyObject.getRevenue());// fix format later
    }

    }
catch (EOFException e)
    {
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

I want to retrieve data from a binary file, which I definitely know that I has data as a objects. But the result of the program is only the below:

```
=================================
List of Ships and their revenue
=================================
```

It probably means that there is something wrong with the try block. Note that this is just part of my program, which relates to the result I want to get. `Ship` is a superclass of the classes to which the object in the file belong. (update: I just print the exception, but no exception is thrown).

Comment: why don't you print the contents of the exception blocks?

Comment: I tried but no exception is thrown

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` inside your `catch` blocks.

Comment: I forgot to serializable and without your suggestion, I cannot find out. Thank @PM 77-1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the looks of it you are in an infinite loop which dies with an exception which results in no output. Try doing the following instead of the giant second try catch block.

```
while(true) {
  try{
    Ship copyObject = (Ship)inputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println(copyObject.getShipName() + "       " + copyObject.getRevenue());
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("No more ships");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I forgot to make the one related class serializable. Though I change my program, it does not make it work. But thank you anyway.

Comment: It would only be accurate to print 'no more ships' when `EOFException` is caught. Any other exception would indicate quite a different problem, which should be printed itself.

Comment: You're right but I posted that really late and was really tired :)